# Do i need to success review from Facebook when i use FB SDK in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

Now i need to use `Facebook` `SDK` from facebook in my iOS App.

So i filled information about my app in `developer.facebook.com` App Detail.

However when i test my app with my device , i can post to facebook without submit and approve from Facebook.

But there is a button to submit app to facebook to review it.

Do i really need to submit and approve my app from `Facebook`? Or i can use `FB SDK` without submit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook's review process is only for apps which create their own OpenGraph objects. If you're just using the Facebook SDK for user authentication and posting to their own feed, then you don't need Facebook's approval.

Comment: ok bro. thz alot. i need to wait about 10 minute to tick your answer. :D