# Do I need to make my "app" public to use FB SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In order to use Facebook SDK in my mobile app, I have had to create an "app" (i.e. Facebook Registration) on https://developers.facebook.com. Right now I am done and my users are happy. But there is a note that says `This app is in development mode` on the Facebook Dashboard. Do I need to change it so to make the app public? Essentially, what difference does it make?

Comment: for the guy who down voted, how is my question so different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043927/do-i-need-to-success-review-from-facebook-when-i-use-fb-sdk-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

If the app is not public only users that have a role (admin, developer or tester) on the app can use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't quite understand it in my context. I am using the Facebook SDK with publish permission so to publish photo for users. Are you saying if the Facebook registration is not public than all the users of my android app will not be able to have their photos posted to Facebook? The word app is ambiguous so I use the word "Facebook Registration"; and keep app for the proper android app.

Comment: No. The word app means that the app id you get from Facebook you can only use for people that are Admins, Developers or Testers of the app. You have to add them as that role in the settings